# Add 1px of Padding(bottom) for Every 1px Scrolled – jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm setting up an animation so that when a user scrolls, after 10px the menu disappears to the left (easy enough thus far).  I would like it so the menu container appears 'fixed' vertically whilst it scrolls horizontally to the left.  I have figured that if I create a loop which adds 1px of padding-bottom to the container for every px scrolled this will create this effect (i can't use position: fixed; because this will prevent the horizontal animation).

I've never approached anything like this before, although I realise I'll need some form of counter to create the px value and then convert into a paddingBottom value.

I've set up the animation so it triggers on scroll, but I seem to be getting absolutely nowhere in terms of how to adding the padding value incrementally.

The code snippet is showing things thus far, but any pointers on how to achieve the above would be amazing.

Emily.

```js
jQuery(document).ready (function($){

  $(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
   $('.mydiv').css('left', '-100px');
 } else {
   $('.mydiv').css('left', '0px');
 }
 });

var divHeight = $('.mydiv').height(),
    scrollTop = $('.mydiv').scrollTop();

 for (i=0; i < scrollTop.length; i++) {

   var divPaddingBottom = 0;

 }
});
```

```css
body {height: 200vh; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .5s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv">
  </div>
```

Comment: It will be very hard to get this right, given that most browsers have [asynchronous scrolling](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/smoother-scrolling-in-firefox-46-with-apz/). Why don't you set the position to fixed and animate the `left` offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```js
jQuery(document).ready (function($){

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.mydiv').css('paddingTop',  $(window).scrollTop() - $('.mydiv').offset().top);
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
      $('.mydiv').css('left', '-100px');
    } else {
      $('.mydiv').css('left', '0px');
    }
  }).scroll();
  
});
```

```css
body {height: 200vh; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  transition: left .5s;
  transform:translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv">
  </div>
```

Note that I applied the css transition only to the left property. I also included transform:translateZ(0); for better performance.